# blank page with views for mobile app

Tags: views, theming

We are building an app. Tried DrupalGap but not going to work with our host.  I need a page that is just a view, for example one that only shows our news items or our cartoons. But no header and no sidebar. We'll need to make a bunch so that we can set them up on the app. If we use the url for our news, then we get the header and sidebar. We made views pages for all our content, but that url also comes up with header and sidebar.

Our rss is fine for newsletter, but really not attractive for an app.

We downloaded the blank page project, but that seems to want to be a home page only, and we need a bunch of them, not at all related to our site, but downloading content from our site.

Hmmmm. Any ideas?

https://thegreeneconomy.com/app-news

Answer (score 0):

In your theme directory, look for a file named views-view.html.twig 
Create a new file, `views-view--yourviewmachinename.html.twig`.

Render your data as you like. Unless you specifically mention it to load base elements, it won't load them.

These articles might help : 
http://redcrackle.com/blog/drupal-8/theme-views-templates
https://www.drupal.org/docs/8/theming